# For $f\in L^1_{loc} (\Omega)$, $f=0$ almost everywhere in $\Omega$ provided $\int_{\Omega}f(x)\Phi (x)dx=0 , \forall \Phi \in C_{c}^{\infty}(\Omega)$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, partial-differential-equations

I need to show that $f=0$ almost everywhere in $\Omega$ provided $$\int_{\Omega}f(x)\Phi (x)dx=0 , \forall \Phi \in C_{c}^{\infty}(\Omega)$$

Here is how I have decided to proceed.

Suppose there exists some measurable set $\bar{\Omega} \subseteq \Omega$ such that $f\neq0$ in $\bar{\Omega}$. I want to show that $\int_{\Omega}f(x)\Phi (x)dx\neq0$.

My problem is coming from the construction of $\Phi$. It has been suggested to me that I approximate $\Phi(x)=\chi_{\bar{\Omega}} $ (indicator function) using convolution.

So let $\Phi_{\epsilon}=\int_{\Omega}\eta_{\epsilon}(x-y)\Phi(y)dy$

I have that $\Phi_{\epsilon} \to \Phi$ a.e. as $\epsilon \to 0$ and that $\Phi_{\epsilon} \in C_{c}^{\infty}(\Omega_{\epsilon}), \forall \epsilon>0$ where $\Omega_{\epsilon}$ is the set with an $\epsilon$-slice removed near the boundary.

Now,
\begin{align}
\int_{\Omega}f(x)\Phi_\epsilon (x)dx &=\int_{\Omega-\bar{\Omega}}f(x)\Phi_\epsilon (x)dx+\int_{\bar{\Omega}}f(x)\Phi_\epsilon (x)dx 
\end{align}

This is where I get stuck. I know the second integral is non-zero, and the first one should go to zero, but I am not sure how to finish off the proof here. Do I take the limit as $\epsilon \to 0$ ? What are things that stop me from just taking this limit?

Thanks for any help! I've been stuck on this for a while.